# callback function cannot accept object as a parameter

Tags: wcf

I found if I defined callback method like

```
void  call(object o)
```

I will received the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

if using

```
void call(string s)
```

then it is good. Anyone knows the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can't use `object` type. Operations (including callbacks) always have to know exact type of parameter otherwise they are not able to perform serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Ladislav, if I have two class, D and B, both are serializable. Can I define callback using call(B b) and pass in the D object? I found in this case , I also encounter the same error. BTW, do you have more documentation about this?

Comment: If you have two different classes you need two different methods. If D derives from B you can use single method but you must also use KnownTypeAttribute on your B data contract to inform service about D type. You can read about data contracts here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: If I cannot modify class B (For example, B is part of .Net Framework), can I still use single method?

Comment: In such case you can try to use ServiceKnownTypeAttribute instead of KnownTypeAttribute.

Comment: It works, Ladislav. If we want to force the callback looks like call(object, eventargs), is there way to achieve it in WCF?

Comment: Probably no, as I already mentioned you need to specify all types which will be transported. You can try to define this operation and use ServiceKnownTypeAttribute to specify all possible types.